# Class methods don't work in after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

My Message model calls `create_notifications` in `after_create`:

```
def create_notifications
  if Message.where(id: 3).first.present? # This message exists!
    puts "Found message" # This never fires when run :after_create
  else
    puts "#{Message.count}" # Returns 1 in after_create, and 125 in console (it only sees the just-created message)
end
```

The problem: Message.where(id:3) doesn't return anything when run in the callback. However, it works when run in console. Also, it works when I run `.create_notifications` on the message manually, after I created it.

Why does `Message.where`, `Message.count`, etc not work when run in an `after_create`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing it with `Message.unscoped.where(id: 3)` worked. Strange because I don't have a default scope or anything. I guess ActiveRecord scopes `where` queries to the just-created query in `after_create`?

Comment: You could log `Message.where(id: 3).to_sql` to see what AR is really doing.

Comment: Turns out it was in fact changing the default scope. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12305

Comment: I find default scopes to be more trouble than they're worth, too much hidden logic for my taste.